# Install packages on centos 7.2 based on packages installed on other centos

Tags: linux, virtualbox, centos, centos-7, yum

I have a centos 7.2 installed on virtualbox, and my customer have a centos 7.2 too. I written a program fir customer and for technical reasons they can not build source on their system. For that I must install every package they have with exact same version on my centos and build source. I've got package list using this command from customer system:

`yum list installed < packages_list`

Now I have packages_list file that contains packages and versions, the file looks like that:

```
...
colord-gtk.x86_64                   0.1.25-4.el7            @anaconda/7.2       
colord-libs.x86_64                  1.2.7-2.el7             @anaconda/7.2       
compat-db-headers.noarch            4.7.25-28.el7           @anaconda/7.2       
compat-db47.x86_64                  4.7.25-28.el7           @anaconda/7.2     
...
```

Now, how I can install exactly same packages with same version on my centos?
I need to keep some packages for development like gcc, make, ...
And other ones should be install with same version.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have configured the same repositories in `/etc/yum.conf` and/or `/etc/yum/repos.d/`

Then, copy the list of packages to the target system.

Finally, if your file is called `installed.txt`, and you've copied it to the working directory of the target CentOS system, try this from a root or `sudo -i` prompt:

```
awk '{ print $1 "-" $2 }' installed.txt | xargs yum install
```